# Does charging my laptop via monitor(usb-c) aid in power supply surge protection?

Tags: laptop, display, power-supply, usb-c, surge-protection

I have a Mac laptop which I can connect with my Samsung monitor with USB-C. This USB-C connection achieves display connectivity and also charges my laptop at the same time. Where I live, there are multiple power supply fluctuations during the day and the supply voltage goes up and down.  So in case there is a wild power fluctuation, will my laptop be somehow protected since there is a monitor in-between?

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but likely yes. If the amount of power is so big it damages the monitor, it is likely to also damage the laptop too though. As in, it will most likely reduce the effect, but not be a complete stop.

Comment: There is a very *small* amount of added protection from having everything plug into a single power supply, avoiding ground loops and faults, such as might occur with split-phase power. More important would be using a surge protector on that circuit, or, even better, a line interactive UPS, which *always* puts itself between the line and the device: https://www.techhive.com/article/578686/best-uninterruptible-power-supply.html